# Migrating from RSpec to Minitest::Spec?

Tags: rspec, minitest

Is there a strategy or set of steps to follow to migrate from RSpec 2 to `MiniTest::Spec`? I'd like to take a look at doing this for a large project but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: I wasn't too impressed with MiniTest when I looked at it recently; I've decided to stick with RSpec for the moment. That said, if MiniTest improves to be competitive with RSpec, this might become a good idea.

Comment: Since the time the previous comment was written Minitest has matured a lot, and is now what is used by Rails, Nokogiri, and many others.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't used MiniTest::Spec for that long, I'm working on porting over some of our tests myself, but here are the few things I've noticed coming from RSpec:

- The matchers are of course different -- it's `must`/`wont` instead of `should`/`should_not`, and predicate matchers are gone so you can't say `must_be_true`/`must_be_false` or the like.
- That said, if you've written custom RSpec matchers, or are using shoulda-matchers or the like, you should be able to use them with MiniTest thanks to the minitest-matchers gem. But YMMV.
- MiniTest::Spec doesn't provide `context`, so you'll need to either change this to `describe` or alias it.
- MiniTest::Spec also doesn't provide `described_class`.
- You also don't have `before :all`.
- `subject` must be set manually (I think, someone correct me if I'm wrong).

So to answer your question, in terms of porting an existing suite of tests, I'm afraid you can't really do a simple find and replace, you'll have to port over each test file one at a time. Obviously, this means you have to determine whether the effort is worth it.

Comment: Minitest supports `subject {}` (I think it probably has to be manual, but then, I always set it explicitly in RSpec anyway), although it doesn't seem to work with the `it {}` syntax. And it has its own sort of predicate matchers—you just have to do `must_be :valid?` instead of RSpec's `should be_valid`.